# Is it possible to send Apple IDFA to Google Analytics manually using Measurement Protocol?

Tags: ios, mobile, google-analytics-api

IDFA and AAID are not in the measurement protocol list of available parameters, but I wonder they are undocumented?

Answer (score 0):

Every Analytics client, ([Android SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/), [iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/), or [Analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)) uses the measurement protocol under the hood. As stated in the reference docs the unique identifier for a user/device is the [`cid` parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#required). Each client populates that unique identifier in its own way.

Note if a user is logged in you can use the [UserID](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662) feature to associate the same user accross multiple devices by sending the [`uid` parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid).

There is also available an [open source hit builder tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) which uses the measurement protocol validation server to verify that a hit is valid.

**The [Analytics Terms of Service](https://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) are very strict about not sending personally identifiable information.**